# Where does EntityKeyValue originate from in miniprofiler sql queries?

Tags: sql, linq, mvc-mini-profiler

I am debugging some duplicate sql statements in my MVC app using miniprofiler.

I'm struggling to find where some sql statements originate and quite a few of these declare a parameter at the beginning `EntityKeyValue`.

For example: `DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 int = 10;`

Is this some kind of internal working of linq / linq to entities?

I've googled it but am not having much joy.  That often means I'm misunderstanding something or missing something obvious - am I?

[image]

**Update**

I've dug around some more and I realise that it is just a parameter.  However most parameters I've seen look like this:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 int = 10;
```

So now my question is - what is the difference between these 2 types of parameter declarations? Where is the EntityKeyValue coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EntityKeyValue` is a parameter that is auto-generated by Entity Framework (see [this file](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/DataClasses/RelatedEnd.cs), line 55).

MiniProfiler captures parameters in the [SqlServerFormatter](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/SqlFormatters/SqlServerFormatter.cs) class.